# Ubuntu 13.10 gparted in loop searching a HD

Tags: gparted

I just updated my Ubuntu to 13.10.
When I start gparted it searches all partitions of /dev/sda, then begins to search /dev/sdb, but never finishes...  The interface continues completelly disabled...
What's wrong ?

Comment: What have you connected as `/dev/sdb` - *since I got my SD card reader working, it use that as virtual device for it, even though no SD card is in it... causing GParted to a bit weird about it* - Anyway, what are you trying to do exactly? If you remove gparted and then re-install it that may help

Comment: /dev/sdb is just the HDD where my Ubuntu 13.10 is installed.
There's another partition with Ubuntu 10.10 installed. And when I boot on it, gparted works fine.
I have removed gparted and reinstalled it, but it didn't work.

Comment: Leaving it to scan/load for while may help - although I once spent half a day waiting for it to finish. Loading GParted from a Live Disk helps - see [here](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php). I know this as I have just finished attacking a 4 month old corrupted Hitachi 1TiB drive with it. Completely skips the installed OS, and runs like one itself (based on Debian). If planning on a big reformat of hard disk this may be best. *Hard disks are supposed to be hard, but this Hitachi one is flippin fragile :-(* - Do you know which version worked and which did not on your Ubuntu setups?

Comment: Fortunatelly, I don't need to use gparted now to solve a real problem. My point of view is "why gparted works fine over Ubuntu 10.10 and not over 13.10 ?".  This means, I will keep the old version installed on my computer. Ubuntu 10.10 works fine all the time. Ubuntu 13.10 isn't so stable. I hope 14.04 be better. Thank you very much for your attention ! GParted Live CD is a very good idea !!!! I'm sorry for your Hitachi HD. My brother had a 60GB Hitachi HD several years ago. It began to show erratic behavior, several bad blocks, weird noise. The data became completelly unrecoverable !!!

Comment: I allowed gparted scanning that partition for several hours. But this forced the CPU temperature to raise a lot, even using cpufreq. Then I **gave up** !
An interesting detail: my 2 hard disks are installed in cases, then I can see their respective LED blinking. When gparted is searching partitions in /dev/sdb, the LED blinks at first then stop blinking. I imagine gparted enters in an loop error... : - (

Comment: In USB connected cases the hard disk sometimes un-mounts - *so I got annoyed enough to take the hard drive out of my laptop, and put the 1TiB in instead*. I then ran GParted off a Live CD, and now (80%) of the disk works - my only problem now is the USB enclosure don't seem to work with it - I think that it was the reason that it corrupted in the first place. I have an eSATA enclosure, I just need to connect it to my G570 laptop... So if the light stops blinking - it has unmounted, and therefore not doing anything - you can see similar behaviour if you unmount it manually.

Comment: My both cases are mounted in the PC case, they aren't USB. /dev/sda is a SATA case and /dev/sdb case is IDE. /dev/sdb is mounted correctly. I can say that it's true because my Ubuntu 13.10 is installed on it !!!!  In fact, in the past I had some problems with external USB cases. My third HD (used occasionally for backup) is installed in an EXTERNAL eSata case.
The reason this brand new version of gparted doesn't work on my brand new Ubuntu is a mystery to me !!!!

Comment: The magic of computers - the thing that is supposed to work does not, and the thing that isn't supposed to work works brilliantly. If you go to Help > About in the working version, you can then find the deb package from [Debian Thing](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=gparted), [Ubuntupdates](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/getdeb_apps/precise/apps/getdeb/gparted) or somewhere. You could even compile it from http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/getdeb_apps/precise/apps/getdeb/gparted

Comment: You haven't been seen in a while, do you still need an answer to this question?